# How following code compiles in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, operators

The following code prints `-10`

```
int x = 10;
-x;
cout << -x << endl;  // printf("%d\n", -x);
```

both in C and C++ compilers `(gcc 4.1.2)`. I was expecting a compiler error for the second line. 
May be it is something fundamental, but I do not understand the behavior. Could someone please explain?

Thanks

Comment: `-x;` negates x and discards result.  same as eg `x+1;`

Comment: Note that in this case, the compiler is likely to optimize out the whole expression as it has no effect. Actually, I would expect any decent compiler to warn you about the unusefulness of such a statement.

Comment: yes, when I give -Wall, I get the warning:

"statement has no effect"

Comment: Ah, good thing you always compile with `-Wall`, eh? Perhaps there's a larger lesson to be learned here...

Comment: Note: If you turn you warning level up the compiler will issue a warning about this. As warnings are usually logical errors in your code (like the above) you can also make the compiler treat warnings as errors. Try: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror <file>.cpp`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Statements can be expressions. Such statements discard result of the expression, and evaluate the expression for its side effects.

`-x;` computes the negation of `x` and discards the result.

For more information read `[stmt.expr]` in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `-x;` the `operator -` is preformed on the variable.
The operator returns the value of the negation, but doesn't change the object itself.

So because you don't store the result of the operator, `x` itself still has the same value.

When you print the `-x` to the `cout`, you see the result of the `operator -` which is returned to the `operator <<`

Comment: `operator-` is not used on built-in types such as `int`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have an assignment statement, or a procedure call statement.
It defines assignment as an operator in an expression, with side
effects, and has an expression statement.  It is expected that the
top level operator in an expression statement have side
effects—that it either modify state, like an assignment operator,
or it calls a function.  But the language doesn't require it, and
expression statements with no side effects whatever are perfectly legal.

A good compiler will output a warning in such cases, since it's almost
certainly a programmer error (and you can usually shut up the warning by
explicitly casting the results to `void`, if for some reason you want
such a statement—the `assert` macro often does this).

Answer (score 0):

Second line has not effect on `x` but is computed. Third has no effect on `x` but the computed output is sent to standard output `std::cout` . To make things a bit simpler to understand:

```
int x=10;
std::cout << x-10 << std::endl;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

will output **0** and **10** .